# ChartJS graph not displaying - line graph

Tags: javascript, php, json, chart.js

I'm trying to get the ChartJS line chart working for a project I am working on. I followed a tutorial as I need to get the data from mySQL database and use this data to be displayed on the line chart. 
I was wondering if anyone had experience using ChartJS and could tell me what's wrong with my code, please.

I have removed the weblink to the JSON data just for privacy reasons, but the data is shown in JSON format.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>ChartJS - LineGraph</title>
     <style>
      .chart-container {
       width: 640px;
       height: auto;
    }
    </style>
    <!-- javascript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/linegraph.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>


 </head>
 <body>

   <div class="chart-container">
     <canvas id="mycanvas" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
       <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
          $.ajax({
         url : "**********",
        type : "GET",
       success : function(data){
       console.log(data);

        var user_id = [];
        var pain = [];
        var sleep = [];
        var mood = [];
        var heartrate = [];
        var time_of_entry = [];


        for(var i in data) {
         user_id.push("UserID " + data[i].user_id);
         pain.push(data[i].pain);
         sleep.push(data[i].sleep);
         mood.push(data[i].mood);
         heartrate.push(data[i].heartrate);
         time_of_entry.push(data[i].timeofentry);

           }

          var chartdata = {
          labels: user_id,
          datasets: [
          {
        label: "pain",
        fill: false,
        lineTension: 0.1,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 0.75)",
        borderColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)",
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)",
        pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)",
        data: pain
      },
      {
        label: "sleep",
        fill: false,
        lineTension: 0.1,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(29, 202, 255, 0.75)",
        borderColor: "rgba(29, 202, 255, 1)",
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(29, 202, 255, 1)",
        pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(29, 202, 255, 1)",
        data: sleep
      },
      {
        label: "mood",
        fill: false,
        lineTension: 0.1,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(211, 72, 54, 0.75)",
        borderColor: "rgba(211, 72, 54, 1)",
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(211, 72, 54, 1)",
        pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(211, 72, 54, 1)",
        data: mood
      },
      {
        label: "heartrate",
        fill: false,
        lineTension: 0.1,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(211, 72, 54, 0.75)",
        borderColor: "rgba(211, 72, 54, 1)",
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(211, 72, 54, 1)",
        pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(211, 72, 54, 1)",
        data: heartrate
      },
      {
        label: "time_of_entry",
        fill: false,
        lineTension: 0.1,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(211, 72, 54, 0.75)",
        borderColor: "rgba(211, 72, 54, 1)",
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(211, 72, 54, 1)",
        pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(211, 72, 54, 1)",
        data: time_of_entry
      }
    ]
  };



  var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

  var mycanvas = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: chartdata
  });
},
error : function(data) {

   }
  });
});
</script>
</div>

 </body>
```

Comment: It's difficult to tell without seeing the dataset. What does `data` from the response look like? Is it sensitive data? Seeing it might help build a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I have copied the data it looks like this - [{"0":"1","user_id":"1","1":"3","pain":"3","2":"3","sleep":"3","3":"3","mood":"3","4":"32","heartrate":"32","5":"2019-06-20 09:52:43","time_of_entry":"2019-06-20 09:52:43"},{"0":"1","user_id":"1","1":"3","pain":"3","2":"3","sleep":"3","3":"3","mood":"3","4":"32","heartrate":"32","5":"2019-06-20 09:52:53","time_of_entry":"2019-06-20 09:52:53"},{"0":"1","user_id":"1","1":"2","pain":"2","2":"23","sleep":"23","3":"3","mood":"3","4":"89","heartrate":"89","5":"2019-06-20 09:53:20","time_of_entry":"2019-06-20 09:53:20"},

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1** - json data is wrong use The [JSON Validator](https://jsonlint.com/) to check.

**Here is the correct json data.**
[{"0":"1","user_id":"1","1":"3","pain":"3","2":"3","sleep":"3","3":"3","mood":"3","4":"32","heartrate":"32","5":"2019-06-20 09:52:43","time_of_entry":"2019-06-20 09:52:43"},{"0":"1","user_id":"1","1":"3","pain":"3","2":"3","sleep":"3","3":"3","mood":"3","4":"32","heartrate":"32","5":"2019-06-20 09:52:53","time_of_entry":"2019-06-20 09:52:53"},{"0":"1","user_id":"1","1":"2","pain":"2","2":"23","sleep":"23","3":"3","mood":"3","4":"89","heartrate":"89","5":"2019-06-20 09:53:20","time_of_entry":"2019-06-20 09:53:20"}]

**Step 2**- parse the json data then use. It will work.

Attached the screenshot.
https://www.screencast.com/t/6t4r6hqMTw

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
              $.ajax({
             url : "**********",
            type : "GET",
        success : function(data){
        data = jQuery.parseJSON( data);

    -------
```

Comment: I tried that there and it still is showing a blank screen - would you know why this may be happening? Appreciate you response

Comment: Remove these two file - <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/linegraph.js"></script>. It's conflicting.

Comment: Thank you I took those out. For some reason, it is not showing on the webpage but I can see it's working on your screenshot

Comment: @emwonderland2828 your json data is not correct. I update the ans please check.

Comment: Great. Glad to help you.:)